# Как изменить правило iptables из php-странички?

Tags: iptables, php, linux

Все перенаправляется на страничку авторизации, после чего, пройдя её, нужно продолжить переход на страничку, при этом отменить PREROUTING. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то подобное делал через [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php). Есть еще [exec()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php). Но с этим надо аккуратно.